# Why are my React components not re-rendering on setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code (simplified for, well, simplicity). I want my Submission components to reveal the author either when individually clicked (works) or when a button is pressed to reveal all of them (does not work).

I've confirmed that the SubmissionList state is being changed when I click the button, and that the initial state of the Submissions is also being correctly set, so why does the setState change not filter down to the Submissions?

I'm sure I'm missing something, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
let Submission = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showAuthor: this.props.revealed
    };
  },

  reveal: function() {
    this.setState({
      showAuthor: !this.state.showAuthor
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    let authorText;
    if (this.state.showAuthor) {
      authorText = " - " + this.props.author;
    } else {
      authorText = "";
    }

    return (
      <li className="submission" onClick={this.reveal}>
        <span className="submissionText">
          {this.props.text}
        </span>
        <span className="submissionAuthor">
          {authorText}
        </span>
      </li>
    );
  }
});

let SubmissionList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      revealAll: true
    };
  },

  revealAllSubmissions: function() {
    this.setState({
      revealAll: !this.state.revealAll
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    let revealed = this.state.revealAll;
    let submissionNodes = this.props.data.map(function(submission) {
      return (
        <Submission author={submission.author} key={submission.id} text={submission.text} revealed={revealed} />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="allSubmissions">
        <button onClick={this.revealAllSubmissions}>Reveal All</button>
        <ul className="submissionList">
          {submissionNodes}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

EDIT: Couldn't actually see my tags written out in the paragraphs. Updated for clarity.

Comment: State should not be set in both components. State should only be set/changed in the parent component. Every child component should essentially be dumb and only use the props that comes from the parent.

Comment: please check the console.. possibly there are some errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want both components to have internal state you need to add [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) handler to `Submission`. And sync props to state there as well.

```
let Submission = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showAuthor: this.props.revealed
    };
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
     if(this.props.revealed !== nextProps.revealed) {
        this.setState({
           showAuthor: nextProps.revealed
        });
     }
  },
  ...
```

But as you can see this results in code duplication. Since now you have 2 sources of state (props and internal component state). A better idea would be to move state to parent component and make `Submission` to be a representational component (w/o internal state)

```
let Submission = ({showAuthor, author, toggle, text}) => (
  <li className="submission" onClick={toggle}>
    <span className="submissionText">
      {text}
    </span>
    <span className="submissionAuthor">
      {showAuthor ? `-${author}` : null}
    </span>
  </li>
)
```

Where `toggle` is a function that switch `showAuthor` for current submission stored somewhere in `SubmissionList` state.

*UPD* you can pass specific toggle that toggles only current submission. For example

```
let submissionNodes = this.props.data.map(function(submission) {
  return (
    <Submission
      author={submission.author}
      key={submission.id} 
      text={submission.text}
      toggle={() => this.toggleSubmissionById(submission.id)} />
  );
})
```

Comment: Might be worth popping an `if (this.props.revealed !== nextProps.revealed)` conditional to inhibit any non-important renders

Comment: @lux Good idea. Added.

Comment: Okay, so I think I get this... mostly. But how do I pass up to SubmissionList that I only want a particular Submission and not all of them to get revealed (when clicking a submission)?

Comment: @dangr You can pass toggle that has current submission id in scope. Check updated answer.